# Proving the divergence of a number-theoretic sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory, irrational-numbers

I have recently been trying to solve a problem involving infinite series, and there is one which I have been able to reduce to a problem in Number Theory, which, however, still gives me trouble. The question is as follows:

> $\forall \alpha \in (0;1)$, prove that the sequence $x_n = ||n\alpha||$ can never tend to $0$ as $n \to \infty$ (here I define $||x|| := \min{(\{x\}; 1-\{x\})} \, \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ as the distance from $x$ to its nearest integer).

The proof is very much straightforward for the case when $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}$, but the case $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ has eluded me for some time.

I have figured that if I could prove that for any monotonic increasing (or decreasing) sequence $r_n$ of rational numbers (all in the interval $(0;1)$) such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}r_n = \alpha \in (0;1)$, the sequence $||nr_n||$ cannot tend to $0$, the irrational $\alpha$ case would follow (and the rational, too, for that matter).

With this, however, I have also had difficulty proving. I should really appreciate any advice you can give me, but bear in mind that I do not want complete solutions, or even significant portions of such. I need only a hint. Thank you.

Comment: $x_n = \frac{n-1}n$ is a monotonic increasing sequence of rationals where the distance of $nx_n$ to the nearest integer limits to $0$.

Comment: You might consider that if $0<x_n \le \frac14$ then $x_{2n}=2x_n$ so there will always be more values  in $[\frac14,\frac12]$

Comment: @ZoeAllen I think here that $x_n$ is defined by $\alpha$ and $n$, with $\alpha$ as a constant

Comment: @Zoe_Allen This is not a valid counterexample, as I stated expressly that the limit $\alpha$ to which the sequence converges belongs to the interval $(0;1)$.

Comment: @Henry Yes, it is something like that. The idea is to constuct a monotonic sequence of rationals converging to the pre-determined $\alpha$. This is essentially why I have used the letter throughout.

Comment: @Henry Could you add just a bit more on your suggestion, please? I don’t see what you mean by $x_n$.

Comment: @Barbatulka You defined $x_n$.  My comment is that if it is ever small and positive then there will be a later value in the sequence which is twice as large, and so by repeating this doubling there will be a later value  between $\frac14$ and $\frac12$, meaning it cannot converge to $0$.  With irrational $\alpha$ it will never be $0$ for $n>0$.

Comment: @Henry But why can it not be that $x_n$ and $x_{2n}$ are both in the interval $(0;\frac{1}{4}]$? According to the relation $x_{2n} = 2x_n$, if $x_n \to 0$ then $x_{2n} \to 0$ as well.

Comment: @Henry I see now what you’re getting at, but I have reservations about the statement $x_{2n} = 2x_n$, even for sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: @Barbatulka  As an illustrative example if $\alpha= \frac1{\sqrt{2}}= 0.7071\ldots$ then $x_{10}= ||7.071\ldots||=0.071\ldots$ and $x_{20}= ||14.142\ldots||=0.142\ldots$ and $x_{40}=  ||28.284\ldots||=0.284\ldots$, doubling the distance from the nearest integer.  You can keep doubling until you exceed $\frac14$

Comment: @Henry Yes, I see that, but the question about $x_{2n} = 2x_n$ remains.

Comment: If $n\alpha=[n\alpha] \pm ||n\alpha||$ with $0<||n\alpha||=x_n\le \frac14$ then $[n\alpha]- ||n\alpha|| \le n\alpha \le [n\alpha] + ||n\alpha||$  and so  $2[n\alpha]- 2||n\alpha|| \le 2n\alpha \le 2[n\alpha] + 2||n\alpha||$   with $2||n\alpha|| \le \frac12$.  So $2n\alpha=[2n\alpha] \pm ||2n\alpha|| = 2[n\alpha] \pm 2||n\alpha||$ and thus  $x_{2n}=2||n\alpha||=2x_n$.

Comment: The argument isn't that $x_{2n}=2x_n$ always. It's that because this holds for $x \le \frac14$ you can never get to a point where every term has $x_n \le \frac14$.

Comment: @Henry I deliberately did not go into detail on your proof of the statement that $x_{2n} = 2x_n$, but I saw the general approach. This gave me the hint I had been looking for. I have now proved the whole result. Your help has been invaluable. Thank you so much!